# Compress file as .tar.gz instead of .zip

Tags: archive, zip, compression, tar

If I right click a file and I compress it I obtain a file.zip. Is it possible to set right click-->compress to produce a file.tar.gz as output? I always have to do it through terminal but many times I'd rather do it with a right click especially when I'm already in the finder looking at the folder

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of ["How do I create a .tgz from Finder using Archive Utility?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226008/how-do-i-create-a-tgz-from-finder-using-archive-utility) ("tgz" is short for "tar + gzip"). Unfortunately, that doesn't have an answer (and I don't think there is one) other than using third-party utilities or creating an Automator Service.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393270/im-trying-to-make-a-service-to-archive-a-folder-using-tgz-i-cant-get-this-to

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write a unix shell script where your commands are to tar the selected files then run gzip on it.

Then you can make this a service and save it at `~/Library/Services`. Then enable it via system preferences > Keyboard > shortcuts > Services.

- [Creating System-Wide Keyboard Shortcut To Launch Applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167967/creating-system-wide-keyboard-shortcut-to-launch-applications/167974#167974)
- [How do I run my automator service without opening automator?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324060/how-do-i-run-my-automator-service-without-opening-automator)

Then you can select a file and right-click on the selected file. At the bottom of the right click menu,  a section for Services appears which has your services. Select your new service and that should do the job.

Alternatively, it can be found in Finder menu > Services.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it as soon as I have some spare time and eventually check your answer!